# Two rows of users getting created in Parse data browser on a single facebook login. Please see details

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, parse-platform, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have integrated facebook login in my app & have joined it with Parse.
So, whenever a user login through facebook, it get stored on Parse.

The problem is that upon logging in once through facebook, 2 rows of users are getting created, as shown below:

[image]

Both users shown above are same. In one row, the name and email is given and on another only facebook id is given.

Here's `SignUpScreen.java` file's code:

```
public class SignUpScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    Button facebookLoginButton;
    CircleImageView mProfileImage;
    TextView mUsername, mEmailID;
    Profile mFbProfile;
    ParseUser user;
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    public String name, email, userID;
    public static final List<String> mPermissions = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("public_profile");
        add("email");
    }};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.content_sign_up_screen);

        mProfileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.user_profile_image);
        mUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userName);
        mEmailID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aboutUser);

        mFbProfile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();

        //mUsername.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        //mEmailID.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        facebookLoginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.facebook_login_button);
        facebookLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(SignUpScreen.this, mPermissions, new LogInCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {

                        if (user == null) {
                            Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                        } else if (user.isNew()) {
                            Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                            getUserDetailsFromFacebook();
                            final Handler handler3 = new Handler();
                            handler3.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    saveNewUser();
                                }
                            }, 5000);
                        } else {
                            Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }

    public void saveNewUser() {
        user = new ParseUser();
        user.setUsername(name);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setPassword("hidden");

        user.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpScreen.this, "SignUp Succesful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(SignUpScreen.this, "SignUp Unsuccesful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("error when signingup", e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void getUserDetailsFromFacebook() {

        final GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(
                            JSONObject object,
                            GraphResponse response) {
                        // Application code
                        //Log.d("response", "response" + object.toString());
                        final Intent profileIntent = new Intent(SignUpScreen.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                        Bundle b = new Bundle();
                        try {
                            name = response.getJSONObject().getString("name");
                            mUsername.setText(name);
                            email = response.getJSONObject().getString("email");
                            mEmailID.setText(email);
                            userID = response.getJSONObject().getString("id");
                            new ProfilePicAsync().execute(userID);

                            b.putString("userName", name);
                            b.putString("userEmail", email);

                            profileIntent.putExtras(b);
                            startActivity(profileIntent);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "name, email, id");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();

    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }
}
```

Please let me know what is causing this thing to happen.

Comment: you are doing login and signup same time. there is no need to signup.

Comment: the user is not getting saved after removing the code which signup.
here is what `logcat` is showing: `error when saving: com.parse.ParseException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot save a ParseUser until it has been signed up. Call signUp first.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating new User in `saveNewUser()`.rather than pass `user` in `saveNewUser()`.

> When `logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground` call it will create one
>   parseUser in Backend and it will return that user after `done`. You can update that user. or you can get that user with `ParseUser parseUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();`

```
handler3.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                saveNewUser(user);
                            }
                        }, 5000);

public void saveNewUser(ParseUser user) {
    user.setUsername(name);
    user.setEmail(email);
    user.setPassword("hidden");
}
```

you can also update your `parseUser` like this

```
public void saveNewUser() {
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();// get current user, no need to pass as arguement
    user.setUsername(name);
    user.setEmail(email);
    user.setPassword("hidden");
}
```

**Note**: `user.isNew()` means you are doing `singup`. you should update user only when `isNew`. otherwise it will update every time when you do `login`